# Permanenly saving a Int in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, int, save

I'm trying to create a game and need to be able to save a number and retrieve it. I've found another tutorial on this but it is outdated and kept giving errors:

```
//To save highest score
var highestScore:Int = 20
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highestScore, 
forKey:"HighestScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

//To get the saved score
var savedScore: Int = 
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as Int
println(savedScore)
```

More Details: It's to save a highscore if that helps (which I don't think it does).

Any help is welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(20, forKey: "HighestScore")

let valueOrZeroIfNotSet = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighestScore")
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserdefaults are a really useful tool, you can permenantly create mutable variables that can be read and written anywhere and anytime. Heres a brief explanation of how to use them.

```
let saves = NSUserdefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

You need to declare a NSUserdefaults to begin, now this is where you will be storing data. Imagine it as a Bookshelf, right now its empty but you can fill it with all forms of information.

Now that we have our 'Bookshelf', we can start filling it with Books, these books can be everything such as Integers, and Strings.

If we want to store my name (Peter) in a 'book' on the shelf, we would first have to create the book and give it a name. The name of the book is called the "key". The key has to be a unique String. Because Im storing my name the key will be "myName". Now we know our key to write to, now lets fill the book with information (Which is my name).

```
saves.setString("Peter", forKey: "myName")
```

Now we've made a book in our bookshelf that stores our name.

We will probably want to read this information just in case we need it! We can access books from our bookshelf easily with:

```
saves.stringForKey("myName")
```

Now we did need the key (the books name) so we could find the right book of information.

Thats pretty much it for NSUserdefaults for you.